# How to change keyboard layout for each user?

Tags: bash, login, keyboard-layout, users, dvorak

I am setting up user accounts for family members on my laptop. I use Dvorak (by touch type) but they will all use QWERTY. How can I set each user to have a different keyboard layout?

Comment: Log in as each user and configure the input type in the relevant section of the control panel. It should then remain as configured for each user. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Béné That works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Each user can set their keyboard layout from Settings and it will be used for that user's subsequent logins.

h/t @Béné